# XML Invoice Data into SQL Table

Tags: sql, xml

I am trying to get xml data into a SQL table.

I have the following Xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Invoice xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2"
    xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2"
    xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2">
    <cbc:UBLVersionID>2.1</cbc:UBLVersionID>
    <cbc:ID>TOSL108</cbc:ID>
    <cbc:IssueDate>2009-12-15</cbc:IssueDate>
    <cbc:InvoiceTypeCode listID="UN/ECE 1001 Subset" listAgencyID="6">380</cbc:InvoiceTypeCode>
    <cbc:Note languageID="en">Ordered in our booth at the convention.</cbc:Note>
    <cbc:TaxPointDate>2009-11-30</cbc:TaxPointDate>
    <cbc:DocumentCurrencyCode listID="ISO 4217 Alpha" listAgencyID="6"
        >EUR</cbc:DocumentCurrencyCode>
    <cbc:AccountingCost>Project cost code 123</cbc:AccountingCost>
    <cac:InvoicePeriod>
        <cbc:StartDate>2009-11-01</cbc:StartDate>
        <cbc:EndDate>2009-11-30</cbc:EndDate>
    </cac:InvoicePeriod>
    <cac:OrderReference>
        <cbc:ID>123</cbc:ID>
    </cac:OrderReference>
    <cac:ContractDocumentReference>
        <cbc:ID>Contract321</cbc:ID>
        <cbc:DocumentType>Framework agreement</cbc:DocumentType>
    </cac:ContractDocumentReference>
    <cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
        <cbc:ID>Doc1</cbc:ID>
        <cbc:DocumentType>Timesheet</cbc:DocumentType>
        <cac:Attachment>
            <cac:ExternalReference>
                <cbc:URI>http://www.suppliersite.eu/sheet001.html</cbc:URI>
            </cac:ExternalReference>
        </cac:Attachment>
    </cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
    <cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
        <cbc:ID>Doc2</cbc:ID>
        <cbc:DocumentType>Drawing</cbc:DocumentType>
        <cac:Attachment>
            <cbc:EmbeddedDocumentBinaryObject mimeCode="application/pdf"
                >UjBsR09EbGhjZ0dTQUxNQUFBUUNBRU1tQ1p0dU1GUXhEUzhi</cbc:EmbeddedDocumentBinaryObject>
        </cac:Attachment>
    </cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
    <cac:AccountingSupplierParty>
        <cac:Party>
            <cbc:EndpointID schemeID="GLN" schemeAgencyID="9">1234567890123</cbc:EndpointID>
            <cac:PartyIdentification>
                <cbc:ID schemeID="ZZZ">Supp123</cbc:ID>
            </cac:PartyIdentification>
            <cac:PartyName>
                <cbc:Name>Salescompany ltd.</cbc:Name>
            </cac:PartyName>
            <cac:PostalAddress>
                <cbc:ID schemeID="GLN" schemeAgencyID="9">1231412341324</cbc:ID>
                <cbc:Postbox>5467</cbc:Postbox>
                <cbc:StreetName>Main street</cbc:StreetName>
                <cbc:AdditionalStreetName>Suite 123</cbc:AdditionalStreetName>
                <cbc:BuildingNumber>1</cbc:BuildingNumber>
                <cbc:Department>Revenue department</cbc:Department>
                <cbc:CityName>Big city</cbc:CityName>
                <cbc:PostalZone>54321</cbc:PostalZone>
                <cbc:CountrySubentityCode>RegionA</cbc:CountrySubentityCode>
                <cac:Country>
                    <cbc:IdentificationCode listID="ISO3166-1" listAgencyID="6"
                        >DK</cbc:IdentificationCode>
                </cac:Country>
            </cac:PostalAddress>
            <cac:PartyTaxScheme>
                <cbc:CompanyID schemeID="DKVAT" schemeAgencyID="ZZZ">DK12345</cbc:CompanyID>
                <cac:TaxScheme>
                    <cbc:ID schemeID="UN/ECE 5153" schemeAgencyID="6">VAT</cbc:ID>
                </cac:TaxScheme>
            </cac:PartyTaxScheme>
            <cac:PartyLegalEntity>
                <cbc:RegistrationName>The Sellercompany Incorporated</cbc:RegistrationName>
                <cbc:CompanyID schemeID="CVR" schemeAgencyID="ZZZ">5402697509</cbc:CompanyID>
                <cac:RegistrationAddress>
                    <cbc:CityName>Big city</cbc:CityName>
                    <cbc:CountrySubentity>RegionA</cbc:CountrySubentity>
                    <cac:Country>
                        <cbc:IdentificationCode>DK</cbc:IdentificationCode>
                    </cac:Country>
                </cac:RegistrationAddress>
            </cac:PartyLegalEntity>
            <cac:Contact>
                <cbc:Telephone>4621230</cbc:Telephone>
                <cbc:Telefax>4621231</cbc:Telefax>
                <cbc:ElectronicMail>antonio@salescompany.dk</cbc:ElectronicMail>
            </cac:Contact>
            <cac:Person>
                <cbc:FirstName>Antonio</cbc:FirstName>
                <cbc:FamilyName>M</cbc:FamilyName>
                <cbc:MiddleName>Salemacher</cbc:MiddleName>
                <cbc:JobTitle>Sales manager</cbc:JobTitle>
            </cac:Person>
        </cac:Party>
    </cac:AccountingSupplierParty>
    <cac:AccountingCustomerParty>
        <cac:Party>
            <cbc:EndpointID schemeID="GLN" schemeAgencyID="9">1234567987654</cbc:EndpointID>
            <cac:PartyIdentification>
                <cbc:ID schemeID="ZZZ">345KS5324</cbc:ID>
            </cac:PartyIdentification>
            <cac:PartyName>
                <cbc:Name>Buyercompany ltd</cbc:Name>
            </cac:PartyName>
            <cac:PostalAddress>
                <cbc:ID schemeID="GLN" schemeAgencyID="9">1238764941386</cbc:ID>
                <cbc:Postbox>123</cbc:Postbox>
                <cbc:StreetName>Anystreet</cbc:StreetName>
                <cbc:AdditionalStreetName>Back door</cbc:AdditionalStreetName>
                <cbc:BuildingNumber>8</cbc:BuildingNumber>
                <cbc:Department>Accounting department</cbc:Department>
                <cbc:CityName>Anytown</cbc:CityName>
                <cbc:PostalZone>101</cbc:PostalZone>
                <cbc:CountrySubentity>RegionB</cbc:CountrySubentity>
                <cac:Country>
                    <cbc:IdentificationCode listID="ISO3166-1" listAgencyID="6"
                        >BE</cbc:IdentificationCode>
                </cac:Country>
            </cac:PostalAddress>
            <cac:PartyTaxScheme>
                <cbc:CompanyID schemeID="BEVAT" schemeAgencyID="ZZZ">BE54321</cbc:CompanyID>
                <cac:TaxScheme>
                    <cbc:ID schemeID="UN/ECE 5153" schemeAgencyID="6">VAT</cbc:ID>
                </cac:TaxScheme>
            </cac:PartyTaxScheme>
            <cac:PartyLegalEntity>
                <cbc:RegistrationName>The buyercompany inc.</cbc:RegistrationName>
                <cbc:CompanyID schemeAgencyID="ZZZ" schemeID="ZZZ">5645342123</cbc:CompanyID>
                <cac:RegistrationAddress>
                    <cbc:CityName>Mainplace</cbc:CityName>
                    <cbc:CountrySubentity>RegionB</cbc:CountrySubentity>
                    <cac:Country>
                        <cbc:IdentificationCode>BE</cbc:IdentificationCode>
                    </cac:Country>
                </cac:RegistrationAddress>
            </cac:PartyLegalEntity>
            <cac:Contact>
                <cbc:Telephone>5121230</cbc:Telephone>
                <cbc:Telefax>5121231</cbc:Telefax>
                <cbc:ElectronicMail>john@buyercompany.eu</cbc:ElectronicMail>
            </cac:Contact>
            <cac:Person>
                <cbc:FirstName>John</cbc:FirstName>
                <cbc:FamilyName>X</cbc:FamilyName>
                <cbc:MiddleName>Doe</cbc:MiddleName>
                <cbc:JobTitle>Purchasing manager</cbc:JobTitle>
            </cac:Person>
        </cac:Party>
    </cac:AccountingCustomerParty>
    <cac:PayeeParty>
        <cac:PartyIdentification>
            <cbc:ID schemeID="GLN" schemeAgencyID="9">098740918237</cbc:ID>
        </cac:PartyIdentification>
        <cac:PartyName>
            <cbc:Name>Ebeneser Scrooge Inc.</cbc:Name>
        </cac:PartyName>
        <cac:PartyLegalEntity>
            <cbc:CompanyID schemeID="UK:CH" schemeAgencyID="ZZZ">6411982340</cbc:CompanyID>
        </cac:PartyLegalEntity>
    </cac:PayeeParty>
    <cac:Delivery>
        <cbc:ActualDeliveryDate>2009-12-15</cbc:ActualDeliveryDate>
        <cac:DeliveryLocation>
            <cbc:ID schemeID="GLN" schemeAgencyID="9">6754238987648</cbc:ID>
            <cac:Address>
                <cbc:StreetName>Deliverystreet</cbc:StreetName>
                <cbc:AdditionalStreetName>Side door</cbc:AdditionalStreetName>
                <cbc:BuildingNumber>12</cbc:BuildingNumber>
                <cbc:CityName>DeliveryCity</cbc:CityName>
                <cbc:PostalZone>523427</cbc:PostalZone>
                <cbc:CountrySubentity>RegionC</cbc:CountrySubentity>
                <cac:Country>
                    <cbc:IdentificationCode>BE</cbc:IdentificationCode>
                </cac:Country>
            </cac:Address>
        </cac:DeliveryLocation>
    </cac:Delivery>
    <cac:PaymentMeans>
        <cbc:PaymentMeansCode listID="UN/ECE 4461"
            >31</cbc:PaymentMeansCode>
        <cbc:PaymentDueDate>2009-12-31</cbc:PaymentDueDate>
        <cbc:PaymentChannelCode>IBAN</cbc:PaymentChannelCode>
        <cbc:PaymentID>Payref1</cbc:PaymentID>
        <cac:PayeeFinancialAccount>
            <cbc:ID>DK1212341234123412</cbc:ID>
            <cac:FinancialInstitutionBranch>
                <cac:FinancialInstitution>
                    <cbc:ID>DKDKABCD</cbc:ID>
                </cac:FinancialInstitution>
            </cac:FinancialInstitutionBranch>
        </cac:PayeeFinancialAccount>
    </cac:PaymentMeans>
    <cac:PaymentTerms>
        <cbc:Note>Penalty percentage 10% from due date</cbc:Note>
    </cac:PaymentTerms>
    <cac:TaxTotal>
        <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="EUR">292.20</cbc:TaxAmount>
        <cac:TaxSubtotal>
            <cbc:TaxableAmount currencyID="EUR">1460.5</cbc:TaxableAmount>
            <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="EUR">292.1</cbc:TaxAmount>
            <cac:TaxCategory>
                <cbc:ID schemeID="UN/ECE 5305" schemeAgencyID="6">S</cbc:ID>
                <cbc:Percent>20</cbc:Percent>
                <cac:TaxScheme>
                    <cbc:ID schemeID="UN/ECE 5153" schemeAgencyID="6">VAT</cbc:ID>
                </cac:TaxScheme>
            </cac:TaxCategory>
        </cac:TaxSubtotal>
        <cac:TaxSubtotal>
            <cbc:TaxableAmount currencyID="EUR">1</cbc:TaxableAmount>
            <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="EUR">0.1</cbc:TaxAmount>
            <cac:TaxCategory>
                <cbc:ID schemeID="UN/ECE 5305" schemeAgencyID="6">AA</cbc:ID>
                <cbc:Percent>10</cbc:Percent>
                <cac:TaxScheme>
                    <cbc:ID schemeID="UN/ECE 5153" schemeAgencyID="6">VAT</cbc:ID>
                </cac:TaxScheme>
            </cac:TaxCategory>
        </cac:TaxSubtotal>
        <cac:TaxSubtotal>
            <cbc:TaxableAmount currencyID="EUR">-25</cbc:TaxableAmount>
            <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="EUR">0</cbc:TaxAmount>
            <cac:TaxCategory>
                <cbc:ID schemeID="UN/ECE 5305" schemeAgencyID="6">E</cbc:ID>
                <cbc:Percent>0</cbc:Percent>
                <cbc:TaxExemptionReasonCode listID="CWA 15577" listAgencyID="ZZZ"
                    >AAM</cbc:TaxExemptionReasonCode>
                <cbc:TaxExemptionReason>Exempt New Means of Transport</cbc:TaxExemptionReason>
                <cac:TaxScheme>
                    <cbc:ID schemeID="UN/ECE 5153" schemeAgencyID="6">VAT</cbc:ID>
                </cac:TaxScheme>
            </cac:TaxCategory>
        </cac:TaxSubtotal>
    </cac:TaxTotal>
    <cac:LegalMonetaryTotal>
        <cbc:LineExtensionAmount currencyID="EUR">1436.5</cbc:LineExtensionAmount>
        <cbc:TaxExclusiveAmount currencyID="EUR">1436.5</cbc:TaxExclusiveAmount>
        <cbc:TaxInclusiveAmount currencyID="EUR">1729</cbc:TaxInclusiveAmount>
        <cbc:AllowanceTotalAmount currencyID="EUR">100</cbc:AllowanceTotalAmount>
        <cbc:ChargeTotalAmount currencyID="EUR">100</cbc:ChargeTotalAmount>
        <cbc:PrepaidAmount currencyID="EUR">1000</cbc:PrepaidAmount>
        <cbc:PayableRoundingAmount currencyID="EUR">0.30</cbc:PayableRoundingAmount>
        <cbc:PayableAmount currencyID="EUR">729</cbc:PayableAmount>
    </cac:LegalMonetaryTotal>
    <cac:InvoiceLine>
        <cbc:ID>1</cbc:ID>
        <cbc:Note>Scratch on box</cbc:Note>
        <cbc:InvoicedQuantity unitCode="C62">1</cbc:InvoicedQuantity>
        <cbc:LineExtensionAmount currencyID="EUR">1273</cbc:LineExtensionAmount>
        <cbc:AccountingCost>BookingCode001</cbc:AccountingCost>
        <cac:OrderLineReference>
            <cbc:LineID>1</cbc:LineID>
        </cac:OrderLineReference>
        <cac:TaxTotal>
            <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="EUR">254.6</cbc:TaxAmount>
        </cac:TaxTotal>
        <cac:Item>
            <cbc:Description languageID="EN">Processor: Intel Core 2 Duo SU9400 LV (1.4GHz). RAM:
                3MB. Screen 1440x900</cbc:Description>
            <cbc:Name>Labtop computer</cbc:Name>
            <cac:SellersItemIdentification>
                <cbc:ID>JB007</cbc:ID>
            </cac:SellersItemIdentification>
            <cac:StandardItemIdentification>
                <cbc:ID schemeID="GTIN" schemeAgencyID="9">1234567890124</cbc:ID>
            </cac:StandardItemIdentification>
            <cac:CommodityClassification>
                <cbc:ItemClassificationCode listAgencyID="113" listID="UNSPSC"
                    >12344321</cbc:ItemClassificationCode>
            </cac:CommodityClassification>
            <cac:CommodityClassification>
                <cbc:ItemClassificationCode listAgencyID="2" listID="CPV"
                    >65434568</cbc:ItemClassificationCode>
            </cac:CommodityClassification>
            <ClassifiedTaxCategory
                xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2">
                <cbc:ID schemeID="UN/ECE 5305" schemeAgencyID="6">S</cbc:ID>
                <cbc:Percent>20</cbc:Percent>
                <TaxScheme>
                    <cbc:ID schemeID="UN/ECE 5153" schemeAgencyID="6">VAT</cbc:ID>
                </TaxScheme>
            </ClassifiedTaxCategory>
            <cac:AdditionalItemProperty>
                <cbc:Name>Color</cbc:Name>
                <cbc:Value>black</cbc:Value>
            </cac:AdditionalItemProperty>
        </cac:Item>
        <cac:Price>
            <cbc:PriceAmount currencyID="EUR">1273</cbc:PriceAmount>
            <cbc:BaseQuantity unitCode="C62">1</cbc:BaseQuantity>
        </cac:Price>
    </cac:InvoiceLine>
    <cac:InvoiceLine>
        <cbc:ID>2</cbc:ID>
        <cbc:Note>Cover is slightly damaged.</cbc:Note>
        <cbc:InvoicedQuantity unitCode="C62">-1</cbc:InvoicedQuantity>
        <cbc:LineExtensionAmount currencyID="EUR">-3.96</cbc:LineExtensionAmount>
        <cac:OrderLineReference>
            <cbc:LineID>5</cbc:LineID>
        </cac:OrderLineReference>
        <cac:TaxTotal>
            <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="EUR">-0.396</cbc:TaxAmount>
        </cac:TaxTotal>
        <cac:Item>
            <cbc:Name>Returned "Advanced computing" book</cbc:Name>
            <cac:SellersItemIdentification>
                <cbc:ID>JB008</cbc:ID>
            </cac:SellersItemIdentification>
            <cac:StandardItemIdentification>
                <cbc:ID schemeID="GTIN" schemeAgencyID="9">1234567890125</cbc:ID>
            </cac:StandardItemIdentification>
            <cac:CommodityClassification>
                <cbc:ItemClassificationCode listAgencyID="113" listID="UNSPSC"
                    >32344324</cbc:ItemClassificationCode>
            </cac:CommodityClassification>
            <cac:CommodityClassification>
                <cbc:ItemClassificationCode listAgencyID="2" listID="CPV"
                    >65434567</cbc:ItemClassificationCode>
            </cac:CommodityClassification>
            <ClassifiedTaxCategory
                xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2">
                <cbc:ID schemeID="UN/ECE 5305" schemeAgencyID="6">AA</cbc:ID>
                <cbc:Percent>10</cbc:Percent>
                <TaxScheme>
                    <cbc:ID schemeID="UN/ECE 5153" schemeAgencyID="6">VAT</cbc:ID>
                </TaxScheme>
            </ClassifiedTaxCategory>
        </cac:Item>
        <cac:Price>
            <cbc:PriceAmount currencyID="EUR">3.96</cbc:PriceAmount>
            <cbc:BaseQuantity unitCode="C62">1</cbc:BaseQuantity>
        </cac:Price>
    </cac:InvoiceLine>
    <cac:InvoiceLine>
        <cbc:ID>3</cbc:ID>
        <cbc:InvoicedQuantity unitCode="C62">2</cbc:InvoicedQuantity>
        <cbc:LineExtensionAmount currencyID="EUR">4.96</cbc:LineExtensionAmount>
        <cac:OrderLineReference>
            <cbc:LineID>3</cbc:LineID>
        </cac:OrderLineReference>
        <cac:TaxTotal>
            <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="EUR">0.496</cbc:TaxAmount>
        </cac:TaxTotal>
        <cac:Item>
            <cbc:Name>"Computing for dummies" book</cbc:Name>
            <cac:SellersItemIdentification>
                <cbc:ID>JB009</cbc:ID>
            </cac:SellersItemIdentification>
            <cac:StandardItemIdentification>
                <cbc:ID schemeID="GTIN" schemeAgencyID="9">1234567890126</cbc:ID>
            </cac:StandardItemIdentification>
            <cac:CommodityClassification>
                <cbc:ItemClassificationCode listAgencyID="113" listID="UNSPSC"
                    >32344324</cbc:ItemClassificationCode>
            </cac:CommodityClassification>
            <cac:CommodityClassification>
                <cbc:ItemClassificationCode listAgencyID="2" listID="CPV"
                    >65434566</cbc:ItemClassificationCode>
            </cac:CommodityClassification>
            <ClassifiedTaxCategory
                xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2">
                <cbc:ID schemeID="UN/ECE 5305" schemeAgencyID="6">AA</cbc:ID>
                <cbc:Percent>10</cbc:Percent>
                <TaxScheme>
                    <cbc:ID schemeID="UN/ECE 5153" schemeAgencyID="6">VAT</cbc:ID>
                </TaxScheme>
            </ClassifiedTaxCategory>
        </cac:Item>
        <cac:Price>
            <cbc:PriceAmount currencyID="EUR">2.48</cbc:PriceAmount>
            <cbc:BaseQuantity unitCode="C62">1</cbc:BaseQuantity>
        </cac:Price>
    </cac:InvoiceLine>
    <cac:InvoiceLine>
        <cbc:ID>4</cbc:ID>
        <cbc:InvoicedQuantity unitCode="C62">-1</cbc:InvoicedQuantity>
        <cbc:LineExtensionAmount currencyID="EUR">-25</cbc:LineExtensionAmount>
        <cac:OrderLineReference>
            <cbc:LineID>2</cbc:LineID>
        </cac:OrderLineReference>
        <cac:TaxTotal>
            <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="EUR">0</cbc:TaxAmount>
        </cac:TaxTotal>
        <cac:Item>
            <cbc:Name>Returned IBM 5150 desktop</cbc:Name>
            <cac:SellersItemIdentification>
                <cbc:ID>JB010</cbc:ID>
            </cac:SellersItemIdentification>
            <cac:StandardItemIdentification>
                <cbc:ID schemeID="GTIN" schemeAgencyID="9">1234567890127</cbc:ID>
            </cac:StandardItemIdentification>
            <cac:CommodityClassification>
                <cbc:ItemClassificationCode listAgencyID="113" listID="UNSPSC"
                    >12344322</cbc:ItemClassificationCode>
            </cac:CommodityClassification>
            <cac:CommodityClassification>
                <cbc:ItemClassificationCode listAgencyID="2" listID="CPV"
                    >65434565</cbc:ItemClassificationCode>
            </cac:CommodityClassification>
            <ClassifiedTaxCategory
                xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2">
                <cbc:ID schemeID="UN/ECE 5305" schemeAgencyID="6">E</cbc:ID>
                <cbc:Percent>0</cbc:Percent>
                <TaxScheme>
                    <cbc:ID schemeID="UN/ECE 5153" schemeAgencyID="6">VAT</cbc:ID>
                </TaxScheme>
            </ClassifiedTaxCategory>
        </cac:Item>
        <cac:Price>
            <cbc:PriceAmount currencyID="EUR">25</cbc:PriceAmount>
            <cbc:BaseQuantity unitCode="C62">1</cbc:BaseQuantity>
        </cac:Price>
    </cac:InvoiceLine>
    <cac:InvoiceLine>
        <cbc:ID>5</cbc:ID>
        <cbc:InvoicedQuantity unitCode="C62">250</cbc:InvoicedQuantity>
        <cbc:LineExtensionAmount currencyID="EUR">187.5</cbc:LineExtensionAmount>
        <cbc:AccountingCost>BookingCode002</cbc:AccountingCost>
        <cac:OrderLineReference>
            <cbc:LineID>4</cbc:LineID>
        </cac:OrderLineReference>
        <cac:TaxTotal>
            <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="EUR">37.5</cbc:TaxAmount>
        </cac:TaxTotal>
        <cac:Item>
            <cbc:Name>Network cable</cbc:Name>
            <cac:SellersItemIdentification>
                <cbc:ID>JB011</cbc:ID>
            </cac:SellersItemIdentification>
            <cac:StandardItemIdentification>
                <cbc:ID schemeID="GTIN" schemeAgencyID="9">1234567890128</cbc:ID>
            </cac:StandardItemIdentification>
            <cac:CommodityClassification>
                <cbc:ItemClassificationCode listAgencyID="113" listID="UNSPSC"
                    >12344325</cbc:ItemClassificationCode>
            </cac:CommodityClassification>
            <cac:CommodityClassification>
                <cbc:ItemClassificationCode listAgencyID="2" listID="CPV"
                    >65434564</cbc:ItemClassificationCode>
            </cac:CommodityClassification>
            <ClassifiedTaxCategory
                xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2">
                <cbc:ID schemeID="UN/ECE 5305" schemeAgencyID="6">S</cbc:ID>
                <cbc:Percent>20</cbc:Percent>
                <TaxScheme>
                    <cbc:ID schemeID="UN/ECE 5153" schemeAgencyID="6">VAT</cbc:ID>
                </TaxScheme>
            </ClassifiedTaxCategory>
            <cac:AdditionalItemProperty>
                <cbc:Name>Type</cbc:Name>
                <cbc:Value>Cat5</cbc:Value>
            </cac:AdditionalItemProperty>
        </cac:Item>
        <cac:Price>
            <cbc:PriceAmount currencyID="EUR">0.75</cbc:PriceAmount>
            <cbc:BaseQuantity unitCode="C62">1</cbc:BaseQuantity>
        </cac:Price>
    </cac:InvoiceLine>
</Invoice>
```

I can get most of the values but I am stuggling to get the InvoiceLine detail. The amount of InvoiceLine detail can be zero or up to 50.

This is my code to date:

```
DECLARE @xml XML
SELECT @xml = BulkColumn
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'D:\OUTSOURCE\UBL-Invoice-2.1-Example.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) x

--insert into Test(Issuedate)
SELECT
    t.c.value('(../*:IssueDate/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') as IssueDate,
    t.c.value('(../*:TaxTotal/*:TaxSubtotal/*:TaxableAmount/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') as TaxAmount,
    t.c.value('(../*:AccountingSupplierParty/*:Party/*:PartyTaxScheme/*:CompanyID/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') as SupplierAccountID,
    t.c.value('(../*:InvoiceLine/*:TaxTotal/*:TaxAmount/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') as LineTax,
    t.c.value('(../*:InvoiceLine/*:Price/*:PriceAmount/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') as Price
FROM @xml.nodes('*:Invoice/*:InvoiceLine') t(c)
```

I read that I can use CROSS APPLY but I am not getting it to work.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change path argument in last two `value` functions. The path to any data of `InvoiceLine` should start at the current node (.), because it is the node selected by `nodes` function.

```
SELECT
    t.c.value('(../*:IssueDate/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') as IssueDate,
    t.c.value('(../*:TaxTotal/*:TaxSubtotal/*:TaxableAmount/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') as TaxAmount,
    t.c.value('(../*:AccountingSupplierParty/*:Party/*:PartyTaxScheme/*:CompanyID/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') as SupplierAccountID,
    t.c.value('(./*:TaxTotal/*:TaxAmount/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') as LineTax,
    t.c.value('(./*:Price/*:PriceAmount/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') as Price
FROM @xml.nodes('*:Invoice/*:InvoiceLine') t(c);
```

Returns

```
IssueDate   TaxAmount   SupplierAccountID   LineTax Price
2009-12-15  1460.5  DK12345 254.6   1273
2009-12-15  1460.5  DK12345 -0.396  3.96
2009-12-15  1460.5  DK12345 0.496   2.48
2009-12-15  1460.5  DK12345 0   25
2009-12-15  1460.5  DK12345 37.5    0.75
```

Comment: Thank you. Really did not see that causing the issue.

Comment: Would it be possible with the returned result to recreate the XML. The reason is that I would need to do a few calculations to make sure the data is correct and then recreate the xml in the original format to send to the invoice application.

Comment: @JCW, yes, you can create XML from result set like that. Another option is using xml `modify` method https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/modify-method-xml-data-type?view=sql-server-ver15 . Ask a new specific question regarding any issuses encountered.